# plural or singular one should use for 60 year/s

Tags: grammar

sixty **year** old company in engineering products has 47 plants

or is it?

sixty **years** old company in engineering products has 47 plants

Answer (score 1):

> The sixty-year-old company in engineering products has 47 plants.

It is 'sixty-year-old' (with hyphens, and singular 'year') because it is being used as a compound adjective to describe the company.

Also, don't forget to include a definite or indefinite article.